# Break line of code with many :not in scss

Tags: css, sass

Maybe it is a silly question but how can I break this line of code (with a lots of :not) so it won't be that long:

```
input {
  &:not(.ant-calendar-input):not(.ant-time-picker-panel-input):not(.ant-calendar-picker-input):not(.ant-time-picker-input) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
input {
  &:not(.ant-calendar-input),
  &:not(.ant-time-picker-panel-input),
  &:not(.ant-calendar-picker-input),
  &:not(.ant-time-picker-input) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

Comment: It would probably be simpler to add a class to the elements that you want to target and use that as the selector; if you have control of the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original SCSS is equivalent to the following SCSS:

```
input {
  &:not(.ant-calendar-input) {
    &:not(.ant-time-picker-panel-input) {
      &:not(.ant-calendar-picker-input) {
        &:not(.ant-time-picker-input) {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which looks a bit nicer as SASS:

```
input
  &:not(.ant-calendar-input)
    &:not(.ant-time-picker-panel-input)
      &:not(.ant-calendar-picker-input)
        &:not(.ant-time-picker-input)
          width: 100%
          height: 100px
```